# how can i make a custom, in-app camera for my iphone app developed in xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, camera, uiimagepickercontroller, photography

i am making a photography iphone app and am after, upon the app being launched, the screen to be a large image where the camera is shown in the center through a hole in the picture - this should be a similar look to that of hipstamatic. since the camera would be open upon launch, i would also need a button to take the picture (but that is not a priority at the moment). i am wondering whether there is an easy way to do what i have described? so far, research has pointed me towards using the uiimagepickercontroller, but using just this did not give me nearly the amount of customization i am after - or am i mistaken and i can do as i described using the uiimagepickercontroller?

right now, this is the code i'm using for the camera - it's currently an ibaction linked to a button that launches the camera once clicked. however, as i mentioned, i would like the camera to open on its own upon opening the app

```
    self.picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
self.picker.allowsEditing = NO;
[self.picker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
[self presentModalViewController:self.picker animated:NO];
[picker release];
```

this code not only navigates away from the current view, but it has all the controls (zoom, tap to focus, etc.), is full screen, and plays that silly animation of the lens opening.

anything you have to offer would be greatly appreciated.
many thanks in advance

zach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`showsCameraControls`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIImagePickerController/showsCameraControls) and [`cameraOverlayView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIImagePickerController/cameraOverlayView) properties of `UIImagePickerController` to add custom overlay above the picker (using a view with a transparent background in which you add some elements as subviews to overlay / frame / mask some parts of the picker if needed.)

You can even use the [`cameraViewTransform`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIImagePickerController/cameraViewTransform) to change the size and position (i.e. the transform) of the camera view that is capturing the camera image.

Comment: great! how exactly can i go about shrinking the size of the camera picker hole? i get that i need to use the cameraviewtransform, but i'm stuck at the moment.